# Log words that start with a letter query with js

Tags: javascript

Trying to log all the words that start with a "b".
I am receiving the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: query[i].charAt is not a function.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
    var query= [34,"beer","bbq","bees","aa","cc", "bb"];


   for(var i=0;i<=query.length;i++){
       if(query[i].charAt(0)=="b"){
           console.log(query[i]);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the first element in your array is a number. `charAt` is only defined for strings. Try this

```
var query= ["34","beer","bbq","bees","aa","cc", "bb"];
```

Alternatively, you can change `query[i].charAt(0)=="b"` to `(query[i]+"").charAt(0)=="b"`. This will for each element of the array, convert it to a string so that then you can call `charAt` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your line with charAt() to:

```
if ( /^b/.test( query[i] ) ) {
```

Also, you have an error in your for loop, it should be:

```
for(var i=0;i<query.length;i++){
```

cause you start with index 0...